# Setting backgroundColor of view in react native covers another element

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a page in my react native app that renders a custom `<Header>` component at the top, followed by a `View` (let's call it BottomView) wrapped in a `Pressable`. The last component rendered as part of the `Header` is also a `View`, namely a thin "line" with a blue-ish color (let's call it TopView). Here is a picture to make it more clear:

[image: Structure]

Now, in the picture shown above, BottomView has no `backgroundColor` set and the TopView has its defined height. So far so good.

However, if I try to set a `backgroundColour` to BottomView (red used here for emphasis), a part of TopView actually gets covered by BottomView as shown below:

[image: TopView getting hidden]

You can clearly see that TopView has about half its original height. Do note that there are no margins, paddings, etc. on any of the elements, and **the only thing changing** is the `backgroundColor` of BottomView.

That is to say, setting `backgroundColor` on BottomView **somehow "pushes"** the View upward.

For reference, here are the styles of the components mentioned:

TopView: `{ borderRadius: 80, borderWidth: 0.5, borderColor: 'transparent', width: '100%', height: '5%', alignSelf: 'center' }`

BottomView: `{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }`

Header View (which wraps TopView): `{ width: '100%', height: '20%', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }`

(Pressable that wraps BottomView has no style applied)

I am at a loss as to how or why this is happening, any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** [Here](https://snack.expo.dev/xq0E7Ej5t) is a minimal example that showcases the problem. You just need to uncomment the `backgroundColor` directive at the bottom of App.js

**P.S.** I am using `"react": "16.13.1"` and `"react-native": "0.63.2"`.

Comment: Can you share the whole component so we can see the stylings and your way to implement those views clearly?

Comment: @SickRanchez I have made a minimal snack that reproduces the error. See my edit above.

Comment: There is no way to understand the issue with all that explanation. It's always better to share the whole case or a showcase. I hope it works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Header.js`, you have 2 views inside a view. For the first view you have `height:100%` and for the second view(that seperator) you have `5%`.

I can't explain it with getting too technical but it looks like an overflow issue.

I just changed the heights to `95%` and `5%` it works fine.

But if I were you, I would make the first view `flex:1` and I would give a constant height for the seperator like 5 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

@SickRanchez's solution is right and I am accepting it as the correct one, because indeed, that aggregate 105% height seems to be causing the issue.

However, for an alternate solution I found, adding `zIndex: -1` to `BottomView` also fixes the problem, as it makes `TopView` render on top of `BottomView` ([ref](https://reactnative.dev/docs/layout-props#zindex)).